# C++ strange problem: cannot find function member in class

Tags: c++, class, member

This problem seems very simple but I cannot solve it no matter what I try...
I have the prototype in the class, there is no duplicate prototypes with the same name nor functions. Yet it can't find it.

Look at these screenshots to see what I mean

[image: 1]

Here is the class where they are added in the header file
[image]

Here is where I try to use the thing where all the functions and variables pop out doesn't have it.

[image]

As you can see in that image the `RemoveParticle` function is in the same area as `FindTargetEffect` function yet it can find the `RemoveParticle` just fine, and `FindTargetEffect` it can't.

If you think it's the defines.. i commented them out and it still doesn't work
[image]

Here is the header class.

```
class CParticleEntityManager {
public:
    friend class CParticleEntity;
    friend class CParticleBundle;

    CParticleEntityManager();

        
    int                     AddParticleToTargetBone(const char *name, 
                                                    DWORD targetID, 
                                                    int effectBoneIndex, 
                                                    bool useEffectBoneRotation, 
                                                    D3DXVECTOR3 &offset, 
                                                    bool autoRemove = true,
                                                    /*bool bNonstopPlay = false,*/
                                                    bool continued = false, 
                                                    D3DXMATRIX matContinued = D3DXMATRIX(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                                         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                                         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                                         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)/*
#ifdef DEF_XMODEL_BONE_EFFECT_OEN_081125
                                                    , bool bXModel = false
#endif
#ifdef DEF_ADD_PARTICLE_OEN_081211
                                                    , float fDelayTime = -1
#endif
#ifdef DEF_BUG_PARTICLE_OEN_090310
                                                    , int nTargetType = 0
                                                    , bool bOverlap = true
#endif*/
                                                    );

    // Ä«¸Þ¶ó Áß¾Ó¿¡ ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼ »ý¼º, ÇÚµé°ª ¸®ÅÏ
    int                     AddParticleToCameraCenter(const char *name, bool autoRemove = true);

    // ÁöÁ¤ÇÑ À§Ä¡¿Í ¹æÇâ¿¡ ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼ »ý¼º, ÇÚµé°ª ¸®ÅÏ
    int                     AddParticle(const char *name, D3DXVECTOR3 &position, D3DXMATRIX &rotation, bool autoRemove = true);

    // ÁöÁ¤ÇÑ À§Ä¡¿¡ ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼ »ý¼º, ÇÚµé°ª ¸®ÅÏ
    int                     AddParticle(const char *name, D3DXVECTOR3 &position, bool autoRemove = true);

    // ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼¸¦ ÀÌµ¿
    void                    MoveParticle(int hEntity, D3DXVECTOR3 &position);

    // ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼¸¦ ÀÌµ¿°ú È¸Àü
    void                    MoveParticle(int hEntity, D3DXVECTOR3 &position, D3DXMATRIX &rotation);

    // ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼ »èÁ¦ (immediately °¡ true ¸é ¹Ù·Î »èÁ¦, false ¸é ÇöÀç»ý¼ºµÈ ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ÀÇ ¼ö¸íÀÌ ´ÙÇÒ¶§±îÁö ±â´Ù¸²)
    void                    RemoveParticle(int hEntity, bool immediately);

    /**
     *  ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼ ¸®¼Â
     * \date 2008-04-23
     * \author oen
     * \param hEntity ¸®¼Â ¿£Æ¼Æ¼ ÇÚµé
     * \param *replace ÆÄÆ¼Å¬À» º¯°æÇÑ´Ù¸é º¯°æÇÒ ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ ¸í
     * \param restart_ ¸®¼Â ÈÄ ÆÄÆ¼Å¬À» ´Ù½Ã ÇÃ·¹ÀÌ ½ÃÅ³Áö À¯¹«
     */
    void                    ResetParticle(int hEntity, const char *replace = NULL, bool restart_ = true);

    /**
     *  ÇØ´ç ÇÚµéÀ» °¡Áø °³Ã¼ÀÇ ºñÀúºíÀ» ¼³Á¤
     * \date 2008-04-23
     * \author oen
     * \param hEntity ÇÚµé
     * \param visible_ true : º¸ÀÓ false : ¾Èº¸ÀÓ
     */
    //void                    SetVisible(int hEntity, bool visible_);

    // ¸ðµç ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °³Ã¼ ¸®¼Â (¿¡µðÅÍ¿¡¼­ »ç¿ë)
    void                    ResetAllParticles();       

    // CMyD3DApplication::RenderView ¿¡¼­ È£Ãâ (postRender ´Â ³ªÁß¿¡ µû·Î ·»´õ¸µÃ³¸®°¡ ÇÊ¿äÇÑ °æ¿ì¶§¹®¿¡ (¿¹¸¦ µé¸é ¹è°æÈ­¸éÀ» ¿Ö°îÇÏ´Â È¿°ú)
    HRESULT                 Render(bool postRender);

    // CMyD3DApplication::FrameMove ¿¡¼­ È£Ãâ
    void                    FrameMove(float elapsedTime);

    // ±ÍÂúÀº DX °´Ã¼ º¹±¸ °ü¸® ÇÔ¼öµé :-(
    HRESULT                 InitDeviceObjects(IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice);
    HRESULT                 RestoreDeviceObjects();
    HRESULT                 InvalidateDeviceObjects();
    HRESULT                 DeleteDeviceObjects();
    
#ifdef _TOOL
    // ÀÌÆåÅÍµéÀ» Á¤¸®ÇÑ´Ù.
    void                    Clear();
#endif

#if defined(DEF_BUG_PARTICLE_OEN_090310) || defined(DEF_EFFECT_OEN_090325)
    /**
     *  µ¿ÀÏÇÑ ID ¿¡ µ¿ÀÏÇÑ ÀÌÆåÅÍ°¡ ºÙ¾î ÀÖ´ÂÁö »ìÇÉ´Ù.
     * \param dwID Ã£À» ID
     * \param strEffectName Ã£À» ÀÌÆåÅÍ ¸í
     * \return Ã£¾Ò´Ù¸é ÇØ´ç ÀÌÆåÅÍ¸¦ ¸øÃ£¾Ò´Ù¸é -1
     */
    int                    FindTargetEffect(DWORD dwTargetID, LPCSTR strEffectName);
#endif

    // ¿¡µðÅÍ¿¡¼­ »ç¿ëÇÏ´Â º¯¼öµé
    int                     m_hTestParticle;
    D3DXVECTOR3             m_testParticleOffset;
    bool                    m_showWireFrame;
    bool                    m_freeze;
    bool                    m_fixPosition;
    int                     m_numDrawParticles;

    bool                    m_bTabSelect;               // Ã¹¹øÂ° ÅÇÀÌ ¼±ÅÃ µÇ¾ú´ÂÁö È®ÀÎ ÇÏ±â À§ÇÑ º¯¼ö

#ifdef DEF_EFFECT_BOX_ESCAFLOWNE_2006_03_16             // ÀÌÆåÆ®Åø ¿¡¹ÌÅÍ

    BOXVERTEX               m_Vertices[ 8 ];
    BOXINDEX                m_Indices[ 12 ];

    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 m_pBoxVB;
    LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9  m_pBoxIB;

    int                     m_nTest;
#endif

    // ÆÄÆ¼Å¬ °´Ã¼ Á¢±ÙÀ» À§ÇØ Á¢±Ù¿µ¿ª º¯°æ
    CParticleEntity *       GetEntityByHandle(int handle);

private:    
    void                    Init();

    int                     GetNewHandle(); 

    int                     GetSortedDrawEntities(CParticleEntity **drawEntities);

    void                    FlushVertexBuffer(prtShaderStage_t *shader, int vbWriteOffset, int vbWriteSize);


#ifdef DEF_EFFECT_BOX_ESCAFLOWNE_2006_03_16             // ÀÌÆåÆ®Åø ¿¡¹ÌÅÍ
    void                    InitBox();                  // ¹Ú½º ÃÊ±âÈ­
    void                    RenderBox();                // ¹Ú½º ±×¸®±â
#endif

    CParticleEntity *       m_pEntities[MAX_PARTICLE_ENTITIES];
    CParticleEntity *       m_pEntityList;
    int                     m_numEntities;
    float                   m_fElapsedTime;

    bool                    m_bConfirmDevice;
    bool                    m_bRestoreDevice;
    bool                    m_bSoftware;

    PDIRECT3DDEVICE9        m_pD3DDev;
    PDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9  m_pVertexBuffer;
    PDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9   m_pIndexBuffer; 
    PDIRECT3DVERTEXSHADER9  m_pBumpEnvVertexShader;
    PDIRECT3DPIXELSHADER9   m_pBumpEnvPixelShader;
    PDIRECT3DVERTEXSHADER9  m_pHeatHazeMaskVertexShader;
    PDIRECT3DPIXELSHADER9   m_pHeatHazeMaskPixelShader;
    CTexture *              m_pHeatHazeTexture;
};

extern CParticleEntityManager   g_particleEntityManager;
```

Comment: Are those actuall errors you get when building, or intellisense errors? Your code makes use of the preprocessor to condionally compile bits and pieces of the class. It could very well be throwing the intellisense off track.

Comment: `FindTargetEffect` is conditionally compiled while `RemoveParticle` unconditionally. Check your macro definitions in effect.

Comment: ya I also think it could be the `defined(..)` command itself, but yeah as you can see I have 2 errors.. the other error is `cannot open source file "StdAfx.h"` which I usually ignore i don't believe that means anything after a while it stops showing that error. 
 You can also see they are purple meaning they do exist and are defined. See look at this image I tried.. still doesn't work https://i.imgur.com/K7Dc4mT.png

Comment: Try to remove none ascii comments, they can lead to unpredictable results, even expose to code while processing.

Comment: @4xy. actually MS compiler supports non-ascii , even in identifiers (that's permitted in standard). But that might be problem, some non-ascii look same as latin1 letters or almost same.Compare `cout` and `соut` - that's two different ids. Doesn't help that c and с are on same key.

Comment: Intellisense database (also Resharper and similar tools) cache result of scan, changes to code which alter  definition or name scopes may cause problem with it, only result of true compilation matters with IntelliSense errors switched off

Comment: @Swift besides support there can be also a bug. Also comments are not code. Multiline comments are ok, but one line can expand to next line accidentally while compiling and affect code producing similar kind issues. I encountered this.

Comment: @4xy that can be happening without non-ascii... \ in end of single line comment (that was GCC bug at least because technically that should not work, MS does catch that but doesn't warn about it) But in 20 years working with non-ascii only I I didn't saw that problem just caused by language of comment (my native Russian, Korean, Polish). But GCC preprocessor had that issue (extracting \ out of unicode)

Comment: What happens if put method definition into the header?

Comment: @4xy Tried that out, still no luck same error. https://i.imgur.com/gNAy475.png interesting chat I got started here :D

Comment: What if try to rename method? Put the declaration to the first line of class (change the position)?

Comment: Make backup and remove all the prepocessor statements and comments from the header and try to compile.

Comment: Position changing doesn't help nor creating new functions also doesn't help none of the new functions wont be detectable either.

Comment: Make header clean of comments and preprocessor and try after that. Also check that you have only one definition of the class

Comment: @SSpoke you mean that adding new method like `void foo(void) {}` leads same result (`foo` is not a memeber)?

Comment: yup no new functions can be added.. i think it may be some old database file.. i'll try deleting vs folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.. I had the same exact header file in a subfolder.

`effect\Effect_Sprite`

and I also had it in the root of the project.

and the root of the project headers were outdated.